# Why is this lambda function initiating class loading in the wrong classloader?

Tags: java, lambda, reflection, classloader

I am working on an application that has a plugin framework.  It uses a custom classloader to load plugins from encrypted jar files.  Initially I painted myself into using the custom classloader as a bootstrapped system classloader.  In this way it worked, but there are some drawbacks in using a custom system classloader.

I am trying to rework so that the custom classloader is only utilized to load the plugins.  The plugins are hierarchical in nature and therefore need the same class context.  To that end, the plugin classloader `CustomClassloader` is a singleton which extends `ClassLoader` and has the parent classloader set to the SystemClassloader (and delegates classloading to parent as is the normal pattern).

This seems to be working well EXCEPT in a particular case where I need to create a lambda function that allows the generic ('reflective') setting of a POJO boolean field that is defined within the plugin.

`lambda_set` creation (defined within an application jar that is loaded by the system classloader):

```
private BiConsumer<POJO_Interface, Object> lambda_set = null;
Class[] parameter = new Class[1];

parameter[0] = field_clazz; // in this case it is boolean.class
set_method = pojo_class.getMethod(setter.trim(), parameter); // setter method name
set_method.setAccessible(true);

MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
MethodHandle target = lookup.unreflect(set_method);
MethodType func = target.type();
MethodType func1 = func.changeParameterType(0, Object.class);
if(func.parameterCount() >= 2)
    func1 = func1.changeParameterType(1, Object.class);

CallSite site = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup, "accept", 
    MethodType.methodType(BiConsumer.class), func1, target, func);
MethodHandle factory = site.getTarget();
lambda_set = (BiConsumer) factory.invoke();
```

When I call `lambda_set.accept(pojo, value);` I get a `ClassNotFoundException` for the POJOs superclass.  Each POJO extends it's own parent abstract class that implements the `POJO_Interface` and contains its fields and getters/setters.  This same function works fine when everything is loaded from the custom bootstrap classloader.  I've verified that it is trying to load the POJO's parent class in the System classloader exclusively instead of the `CustomClassloader` which is wrong.

I've verified that the `pojo.getClass().getClassLoader() == pojo_class.getClassLoader() == CustomClassloader.class`  However, the `lambda_set.getClass().getClassLoader() == jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader`.  I'm not sure if this is the problem.

This behavior is the same in JDK8-JDK14.

Is there a way that I can make the `lambda_set` utilize my `CustomClassloader` when it needs to load a class?  Any other insights would be appreciated!

I've also tried setting the application main thread ContextClassloader and verified that the `lambda_set` is being called from a thread who's ContextClassLoader is the `CustomClassloader`.  This results in the same behavior desicribed above.

```
    static {
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(new CustomClassloader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()));
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {...}
```

Comment: The thread’s context class loader is entirely irrelevant. To anything in the JVM. For the `LambdaMetafactory`, the lookup object defines the context. You are passing the result of `MethodHandles.lookup()` which encapsulates the context in which the `MethodHandles.lookup()` expression is contained. The fix is to provide a lookup representing a context which can resolve the type, e.g. encapsulating the target method’s declaring class.

Comment: @Holger Thank you for putting me on the right track!  Very insightful.  Please let me know if you have any additional suggestions for the answer I wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Holger's comment:

> {...} You are passing the result of MethodHandles.lookup() which encapsulates the context in which the MethodHandles.lookup() expression is contained. The fix is to provide a lookup representing a context which can resolve the type, e.g. encapsulating the target method’s declaring class. – Holger

And additionally digging through the `MethodHandles` source code some we see clearly what Holger is referring to:

```
    /**
     * Returns a {@link Lookup lookup object} with
     * full capabilities to emulate all supported bytecode behaviors of the caller.
     {...}
     */
    @CallerSensitive
    @ForceInline // to ensure Reflection.getCallerClass optimization
    public static Lookup lookup() {
        return new Lookup(Reflection.getCallerClass());
    }
```

The call to `Reflection.getCallerClass())` is what is tying the context to the class from the wrong classloader.

This led me to look for an alternative, and one presented itself within the `MethodHanldes` source comments/methods:

```
    /**
     * Returns a {@link Lookup lookup} object on a target class to emulate all supported
     * bytecode behaviors, including <a href="MethodHandles.Lookup.html#privacc">private access</a>.
     {...}
     */
    public static Lookup privateLookupIn(Class<?> targetClass, Lookup caller) 
        throws IllegalAccessException {...}
```

With this understanding, I have updated the code from the question to the following:

```
private BiConsumer<POJO_Interface, Object> lambda_set = null;
Class[] parameter = new Class[1];

parameter[0] = field_clazz; // in this case it is boolean.class
set_method = pojo_class.getMethod(setter.trim(), parameter); // setter method name
set_method.setAccessible(true);

MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();

/////// FIXED //////////
lookup = MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(pojo_class, lookup);
/////// FIXED //////////

MethodHandle target = lookup.unreflect(set_method);
MethodType func = target.type();
MethodType func1 = func.changeParameterType(0, Object.class);
if(func.parameterCount() >= 2)
    func1 = func1.changeParameterType(1, Object.class);

CallSite site = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup, "accept", 
    MethodType.methodType(BiConsumer.class), func1, target, func);
MethodHandle factory = site.getTarget();
lambda_set = (BiConsumer) factory.invoke();
```

Fortunately, in my case everything is under the same module name, so I was able to utilize the existing `lookup` in the call to `MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(Class<?> targetClass, Lookup caller)`.

With the change, this function now works correctly.  Once again, thank you Holger for steering me in the right direction.

For additional information, Holger has also answered related questions:

[LambdaMetafactory to access class on a different ClassLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48441650/549939) and [Use LambdaMetafactory to invoke one-arg method on class instance obtained from other classloader](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50787116/549939) (for Java 8)

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood my use of the term “encapsulating”. The `Lookup` object always encapsulates a context. I was just saying, you need to get a lookup object encapsulating an appropriate context, just what you did with `privateLookupIn` I now found [LambdaMetafactory to access class on a different ClassLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48441650/2711488) which already discussed this and it links to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50802998/2711488) which shows how to do it prior to Java 9 or when the code is not in the same module, but has access to the custom class loader

Comment: You're right.  I thought you were indicating I could call the `MethodHandles.lookup()` from the `pojo_class` there by gaining the correct context (which is true).  I linked to the questions you mentioned in the answer.  I appreciate the information, I think this problem may have been what pushed me down the bootstrap classloader path in the first place.